# Can I use EV3 with a TETRIX motor?

Tags: ev3, motor, 3rd-party, labview

What program can I use to control a TETRIX motor through the LEGO EV3? I've heard that RobotC currently cannot be used for this.

Has NI released a Labview version which I can use to control TETRIX through EV3?

Comment: Do you mean the [HiTechnic Motor Controller](http://www.hitechnic.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/HiTechnic-Motor-Controller-Specification.pdf) or something else?

Comment: I do mean the HiTechnic Motor Controller. Thanks :)